# stop a reading when read = 0

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I'm trying to do something like these:

```
  while[$read!="0"];
```

In this program

```
 #!/bin/sh
 i=0
 cont=0
 while[$read!="0"]; do
     read number
     cont=`expr $cont + $number`
     i++
 done
 cont=`expr $cont / $i -1`
 echo
```

I want to stop suming the entries when I give it a 0
tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you're reading into is `$number`, so reference that rather than `$read` in your loop.

Whitespace is significant, so make sure to include spaces before, after, and between all of the items in your loop. (Confusingly, you must *not* include spaces in an assignment statement like `i=0`. `i = 0` is wrong.)

For good measure, use double quotes around the variable. That's a good practice so that if the user hits enter without typing a number your script doesn't barf on the empty string.

```
while [ "$number" != "0" ]; do
```

Also, your `i++` isn't right. There are various ways to write that, the simplest being:

```
let i++
```

Answer (score 0):

In this, an infinite loop would be appropriate, since you know the condition on which you want to (hint) `break` out of the loop. The way to get an infinite loop in sh is: `while true; do ...; done`

Also, `read` has a `-p` option that lets you have a prompt (so you know what you're being asked to enter): `read -p "Enter a number: " number`